# Creating a new column of extracted string sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **`summary`** with columns - `Team Name` and `Result`in SQL.

Sample values:

```
Team Name | Result
team one  | team one won by 10 points
Champions | Champions lost by 15 points
Patriots  | Match tied
```

How do I get only the words 'won','lost' or 'tied' in a separate column? The team names maybe of multiple words.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You come perilously close to natural language processing here. What if you have a team called `LosTigres`? Do they lose every game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select (case when s.result like '% won %' then 'won'
             when s.result like '% lost %' then 'lost'
             when s.result like '% tied%' then 'tied'
        end) as result
from t;
```

This might have some issues if the team name has the words "win", "lost", or "tied".  This seems unlikely, but you can protect against it with:

```
select (case when s.result like team_name || ' ' || ' won %' then 'won'
             when s.result like team_name || ' ' || ' lost %' then 'lost'
             when s.result = team_name || ' tied' then 'tied'
        end) as result
from t;
```

Comment: Exactly this and maybe this could be interesting for you: [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Answer (score 1):

SQL code below (instr function used):

```
select s.*, case
  when instr(upper(s.result),'WON')>0 then 'W'  
  when instr(upper(s.result),'LOST')>0 then 'L'  
  when instr(upper(s.result),'TIED')>0 then 'T'  
  else '?' end as res
from summary s
```